# Is there a way to stopPropagation for a specific namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery

suppose we create an event listener like so:

```
$(element).on("click.namespace",function(e){alert('hi')});
```

now I have another event on a div inside which I want to stop the first one, keeping the other click events:

```
$(element).find('div').on("click",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); //I want it to stop only the previous function
});
```

is there a way to stop the propagation only for this specific namespace? allowing all other functions to run as normal?

it has to be namespace related since the event I want to stop is in an external library

Comment: So you want to prevent the execution of the namespaced event handler on the **same** element? If yes, it looks like you are looking for http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/. Note that the handler who calls this function must be bound first.

Comment: not exactly, this is just for the sake of simplicity, the event handler I want to stop is bound to html, but when someone clicks my dropdown I want it to keep itself open. so I need to stopPropagation of this click event, but only at the dropdown namespace, so other click events can go on

Comment: OK, lets see if I understand it correctly now: There is some third party code that binds event handlers with a namespace and e.g. on `click`, you want to prevent the execution of all `click.namespace` handlers?

Comment: I edited the question to try to explain it a little better, thanks for the help

Comment: I cannot imagine a way to do that, without modifying jQuery itself. There is no way to exclude namespaces from the event execution.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use the not opertor

```
$(element+":not(tags to be avoided)").on("click.namespace",function(){
 alert('hi')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add as a class, then check it.

```
$(element).on("click", function(evt){
   if ($(this).hasClass('namespace')) {
       evt.stopPropagation();
   }
   alert('hi');
});
```